# SQL GROUP BY usages

Tags: sql, sqlite, transformation

I am doing SQL transformation lesson from Codecademy [here](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/sql-table-transformation/lessons/subqueries/exercises/non-correlated-iii?action=lesson_resume). I am not sure why they are using those numbers after GROUP BY clause and what those numbers are doing. Can anyone passed the course be so kind to let me know?

```
SELECT dep_month,
          dep_day_of_week,
           dep_date,
           COUNT(*) AS flight_count
      FROM flights
     GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Comment: On a sidenote: In a well-built database you wouldn't have `dep_month` and `dep_day_of_week`, because both can be got from `dep_date` obviously. In a database we strive not to store information redundantly, because that may lead to inconsistencies (e.g. a month that doesn't match the month in the date).

Comment: Another sidenote: In real life most queries have an `ORDER BY` clause. You usually wouldn't group by date and then show the result not ordered by date. But well, if you read the results into some GUI grid that orders the data itself, you may of course fill it with an unordered data set. So I am not saying that queries without `ORDER BY` don't exist. They are just not as common.

Answer (score 6):

The numbers in the `GROUP BY` clause simply refer to the columns in the `SELECT` list, from left to right.  Hence, your query is identical to the following:

```
SELECT
    dep_month,
    dep_day_of_week,
    dep_date,
    COUNT(*) AS flight_count
FROM flights
GROUP BY
    dep_month,
    dep_day_of_week,
    dep_date
```

The above query which I wrote is what I would use in practice.  The reason for this is that `GROUP BY 1,2,3` refers to *positions* rather than columns.  If someone refactors the `SELECT` later, he runs the risk of breaking your query.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously these are position numbers. So this is a `GROUP BY` on the first three columns:

```
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

means

```
GROUP BY dep_month, dep_day_of_week, dep_date
```

here.

This is not compliant with the SQL standard, because the `GROUP BY` clause is supposed to be executed *before* the `SELECT` clause, so the positions cannot be known. They are only known in the `ORDER BY` clause, because that occurs after the `SELECT` clause. Only few DBMS make an exception and allow this positional declaration in `GROUP BY`. It's bad hence to show this in a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

It's basically group by column 1, column 2 and column 3 from your select query.